# Какая самая короткая (по синтаксису) сортировка в СИ?

Tags: c, сортировка

Здравствуйте!

В языке C есть сортировка qsort.
Выглядит примерно так:

```
....
#include <stdlib.h>     /* qsort */
int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

....
  qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
....
```

Есть ли более короткая форма записи или аналогичные функции в ещё меньшее количество символов?

PS Просто запись отдельно функции *compare* слишком велика, требуется более короткая. Может *qsort* без неё и т.д.

PPS Зачем? Для краткости записи, буду писать на бумаге.

Comment: Меня одного интересует такой вопрос?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, боюсь, мы редко пишем на бумаге

Comment: @Fike, мне для ЕГЭ )).

Comment: учитывая, что вопрос, скажем так, странный, то видимо, да, одного. 
Си - язык в общем-то весьма простой и незамысловатый, а потому в нем нет лямбда-функций, шаблонов и прочих простых радостей трудового народа, которые могли бы облегчить эту задачу. Кроме того, почему бы вам не объявить один раз уже указанную тут функцию compare, а потом везде  использовать достаточно лаконичную qsort с коллбэклом в виде compare (как вы и описали выше). Полагаю, это вряд ли сожрет весь имеющийся запас бумаги

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, а Вы в курсе, что для сравнения целых правильно писать

    return a < b ? a : b;

а не 

    return a - b;

который можно использовать только для небольших чисел?

--

Почитайте про переполнения. Например, узнаете, что INT_MIN == -INT_MIN 

(если не верите, то попробуйте 

    int a = INT_MIN;
    printf ("%d %d\n", a, -a);

и расскажите всем знакомым).

Comment: @avp, небольшое уточнение, разве не

   return a < b ? -1 : 1;

Comment: @insolor, Вы абсолютно правы. Моя ошибка (что-то не о том подумал, написал как в вычислении `min(a,b)`). 

Правильно вообще вот  так:

     return (a == b) ? 0 : (a < b) ? -1 : 1;

При равенстве в компараторах принято все-таки возвращать 0. Это может повлиять на эффективность алгоритма сортировки.

Comment: Уважаемые участники, Код который приведён в моём вопросе взять с сайт cplusplus, так что пишите им замечания.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК: Да, cplusplus.com известен своими ляпами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Гномья сортировка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Код на С будет ещё более лаконичным за счёт постфиксных операций.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, По вашему это более короткая(с точки зрения количества символов) сортировка?

Comment: Каюсь, невнимательно прочел вопрос. Я думал, подразумевается лаконичность алгоритма.

Comment: Тогда уж (IMHO) подобная дурь со сложностью O(n^3) (название мне неизвестно, но где-то в сети оно наверняка есть):

    #define SWAP_PREV(a,i) ({typeof(a[0]) _t = a[(i)]; a[(i)] = a[(i) - 1]; a[(i) - 1] = _t;})
    
    void dummysort (int a[], int n) {
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] < a[i - 1]) {
          SWAP_PREV(a, i);
          i = 0;
        }
    }

явно короче.

Comment: Это сортировка перестановкой, ее временная сложность O(n * n!).

Кстати, есть сортировка еще дурее - Bogosort: перемешать случайно, проверить порядок, опять перемешать... Если функции для случайно заполнения и перемешивания уже есть, получается одна строчка

    while( !sorted(arr, siz) ) { shuffle(arr, siz); }

Кстати, для сверхкороткого массива (3-5 элементов), особенно сортирующегося нечасто (например, при старте программы) может быть вполне приемлема (лишний повод отойти от экрана). Средняя сложность - такая же, O(n * n!). Ключевое слово - средняя. Теоретически она может работать вечно...

Comment: @VadimTukaev, вот O(n!) для dummysort() -- это вряд ли.

Конечно, `i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz` не самый медленный процессор, но что-то слабо верится, что 1000 rand эта дурацкая программа  смогла бы отсортировать за `real  0m0.357s` при сложности алгоритма O(n!).

А вот сортировка 10000 rand за `real  5m1.695s`  по сравнению с временем сортировки 1000 rand -- это скорее похоже на O(n^3).

Comment: Я всего лишь процитировал Википедию. Можете поспорить с ней, если хотите.

Может, для Богосорт подразумевается все-таки, что она "понимает", сколько элементов отсортировано (функция sorted возвращает количество, а не просто true/false), и "сортирует" (т.е. перемешивает) только оставшиеся?